# Degree 1 Representation : Explain why we can identify a representation to it's character.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $(p,V)$ be a degree 1 representation over an abelian finite subgroup for example.

From what i understand , we have $GL(V)$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C^*}$ and we can identify $p(g)$ and $\chi_p(g)$ (it's character) for all $g \in G$.

I'm not very at ease with this identification : if we consider a trivial representation of a abelian finite group , let's say $p_{id}$ , then $p_{id}(g)$=$Id$ for all $g\in G$, so we can identify $Id$ with the complex number 1 and deduce our character value on conjugacy classes of G for example. But it would be a trivial example and it doesn't guarantee me to have really understand how we generally choose the identification.

Maybe the exhibition of an isomorphism would help me to understand.

Comment: Huh?  We have a very natural isomorphism of $1\times 1$ matrices with the trace of the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user10354138, completing for the answer to be answered :

$\phi : GL(V) \rightarrow \mathbb{C^*},M\rightarrow tr(M)$ where V is a 1-dimensional complex vectorial space defines a natural isomorphism.